# Combine arrays, but in a specific way

Tags: php, arrays

I have not even started the codeing process, because i cant figure out the logic.

I have 2 arrays

```
$urls = array(0 => url1, 
              1 => url2, 
              2 => url3, 
              3 => url4);

$domains = array(0 => domain_a, 
                 1 => domain_b, 
                 2 => domain_c, 
                 3 => domain_d);
```

i need and output like

```
[0] => array ( [domain] => domain_a
               [urls] => array ( 
                                [0] => url2, 
                                [1] => url4 ))
[1] => array ( [domain] => domain_b
               [urls] => array ( 
                                [0] => url1, 
                                [1] => url3 ))
[2] => array ( [domain] => domain_c
               [urls] => array ( 
                                [0] => url1, 
                                [1] => url4 ))
[3] => array ( [domain] => domain_d
               [urls] => array ( 
                                [0] => url2, 
                                [1] => url3 ))
```

Until all domains has bin packed with 2 urls. The packing of the urls must be random, but the use of each url must be the same, or close to the same.

Comment: Where is for `domain_d`? You mean equal or near to equal frequency for each URL?

Comment: domain_d should have bin there, but i just cut it short, was making dots like this ...., but i dont know where they went.

Comment: As for the frequency, it cannot allways cut it equal, like the ex.

Comment: As in the example, each URL has evenly appeared twice.

Comment: Say the average division happens to be 3.725. So you want frequencies as 3,3,4,4... ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This looks like a good exercise to learn some test-driven development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ever can't do something, the best thing is to break it down into chunks.

The answer to your question is likely to create a copy of the array of urls, and loop through the domains adding two of these urls each time — at random. When you do so, remove the item from the array. If the copy of urls is empty, create a fresh copy.

```
// The output
$output = [];
// The selection of arrays. We can populate this later...
$selection = [];

// Loop through every domain...
foreach($domains as $domain){
  // Create the template that you want in the output. So far this is nearly the whole way there, we just need to add the random urls
  $newItem = [
    "domain" => $domain,
    "urls" => []
  ];

  // You want 2 urls per domain, so we'll do a for loop twice. ($i < 2)
  for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){

    // If the $selection list is empty (it will be at the start of the function, and also in your example on domain_c make a simple copy of the urls)
    if(count($selection) <= 0){
      $selection = $urls;
    }

    // Now find a random key for an item in the array
    $randomKey = array_rand($selection);

    // Push the item into the array of urls
    $newItem["urls"][] = $selection[$randomKey];

    // remove it from the array of items to pick from (so it won't come up again until you create a new copy, after all the others are used)
    unset($selection[$randomKey]);
  }
  
  // Add this to the output:
  $output[] = $newItem;
}
```

Comment: I accidentally wrote a JavaScript `var` earlier... make sure that is removed in the loop :)

Comment: Aweseme respons! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using `shuffle()` and a simple `foreach` should be enough to do the job. For an arbitrary number of domains to be distributed randomly onto another number of urls use the following script:

```
$url=array('url1','url2','url3','url4');
$dom=array('dom_a','dom_b','dom_c');

$urls=$url;       // copy the array
shuffle($urls);   // shuffle the domains
$ul=count($urls); // length of $url
$dl=count($dom);  // length of $dom

foreach ($urls as $k => $u)
  $res[$k]=["domain"=>$dom[$k%$dl], "urls"=>[$u,$urls[($k+1)%$ul]]];

print_r($res);
```

See DEMO here: https://rextester.com/PFS53297

Comment: I think he wants an even spread of each, so if there are 2 domains and 4 urls, all 4 always show (in a random order)

Answer (score 0):

This code provides for a different number of domains and URLs in the input:

```
$urls = array(
    0 => 'url1',
    1 => 'url2',
    2 => 'url3',
    3 => 'url4'
);

$domains = array(
    0 => 'domain_a',
    1 => 'domain_b',
    2 => 'domain_c',
    3 => 'domain_d'
);
$result = [];
foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    $urlsBucket = [];
    while (count($urlsBucket) < 2) {              // We need only 2 URLs
        $randomUrl = $urls[array_rand($urls)];    // Get random URL
        if (in_array($randomUrl, $urlsBucket)) {  // To avoid duplication in the URL list
            continue;
        }
        $urlsBucket[] = $randomUrl;
    }
    $result[] = [
        'domain' => $domain,
        'urls'   => $urlsBucket
    ];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["domain"]=>
    string(8) "domain_a"
    ["urls"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "url2"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "url1"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["domain"]=>
    string(8) "domain_b"
    ["urls"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "url2"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "url4"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["domain"]=>
    string(8) "domain_c"
    ["urls"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "url3"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "url1"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["domain"]=>
    string(8) "domain_d"
    ["urls"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "url1"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "url2"
    }
  }
}
```

DEMO: https://paiza.io/projects/c9rXHcprCgsWnUlJ9UNNsg?language=php

Comment: Beware of using `while` — if there is only one URL in the `$urls` list this may cause an infinite loop :S